# Which of the two sentences below is more gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-order

I'm having difficulty choosing between the two sentences below. Which is more grammatically correct? Can anyone suggest a more succinct way of articulating what I am trying to say?

1. While donning his personal protective equipment a loose strap flew up and hit him in the head.
2. While donning his personal protective equipment a strap connected to his respirator flew up and hit him in the head.

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: To be pedantic, it should be 'While _he was_ donning his equipment...', otherwise the literal meaning is that the strap was donning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *donning*, not dawning. They're both grammatical, but the second one is too long and needs to be split up (style).

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions? Do you suggest instead using two sentences to try and articulate my point?

Comment: If you're writing an accident report, it's reasonable.  If you're writing a story, it's much too dull.

Comment: @AlexK Sure, e.g.: He began to put on his ... equipment. Before he could finish, his respirator strap flew up ...

Comment: Thank you. Johnny, in this case, would it not be more correct to refer to "the respirator" as opposed to "his respirator"?

Comment: Hellion, what makes you say that it would be too dull to include as part of a story?